# How to convert windows timezone to moment js timezone

Tags: c#, timezone, momentjs, aurelia, moment-timezone

i have a dropdown to select timezone in UI. 
[image]
that dropdown data taken from windows timezone settings dropdown list
[image]

If logged user in selected some timezone, i have to display all datetime fields according to selected timezone format with DST.

My table structure is
[image]

Typescript ts code

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import * as momenttimezone from 'moment-timezone';

private ConvertServerTimezoneToClient(dateTime: string, dateFormat: string, timeFormat: string, timezoneFormat: string, isDstzone: string) {
    timeFormat = timeFormat.toString().indexOf('tt') > -1 ? timeFormat.replace('tt', 'a') : timeFormat;
    var convertedTime = '';
    if (timezoneFormat && timezoneFormat != '' && timezoneFormat != "null") {
        if (isDstzone == 'true') {
            momenttimezone.tz.add(''); // need to map
            momenttimezone.tz.link(''); // need to map
            var zoneName = ''; // need to map
            var isDstDate = momenttimezone.tz(new Date(dateTime), zoneName).isDST();
            if (isDstDate) {
                convertedTime = moment(dateTime).zone(timezoneFormat).add(1, 'hours').format(dateFormat + ' ' + timeFormat);
            } else {
                convertedTime = moment(dateTime).zone(timezoneFormat).format(dateFormat + ' ' + timeFormat);
            }
        }
        else {
            convertedTime = moment(dateTime).zone(timezoneFormat).format(dateFormat + ' ' + timeFormat);
        }
    }
    return convertedTime
}
```

Moment js have more timezone formats
https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json

How to map windows timezone to moment timezone. UI base code is with aurelia typescript. Need help.

Comment: This is better handled server side with [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter), assuming you are running .NET in your server-side code.

Comment: Also, your code shown here has several bugs. You should not be trying to add an hour for DST manually. Moment-timezone has all that built in.  Also you probably have several other susbtitutions to make besides tt to a.

Answer (score 2):

There is no quick or easy way to do this. Momentjs doesn't support it and isn't planning to either - for the same reason why you should really be doing this on the server, rather than on the client. If you need your timezones in Windows format in .NET code, [use NodaTime on your server to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088984/convert-windows-timezone-to-moment-js-timezone).

If for one reason or another you still insist on doing this on the client, you could use the [official file for conversion between Windows and IANA timezones](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml). Parse that file and then use it to do your mappings.

All else aside, I would strongly recommend working with UNIX timestamps instead of strings. It's **much** easier to pass an unambigious number around that every decent DateTime library will know how to convert properly, than to keep track of and properly parse a string timestamp everywhere.

Comment: also consider this answer to a similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17348822/4099159)