# How can use "Romance Standard Time" to set the time zone?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, browser, timezone

I have the UTC date string `"2022-01-06T13:35:00Z"` and the time zone string `"Romance Standard Time"`. How can use that time zone string in JavaScript (in a browser) so that I can get the time corrected to `14:35`?

The time zone libraries that I have found so far uses the IANA time zone, e.g. `"Europe/Copenhagen"`, so a library that can convert `"Romance Standard Time"` to something like `"Europe/Paris"` would also answer my question. It's acceptable that this conversion is done in .NET and not JavaScript.

Comment: Do you want it for both .NET and JS?

Comment: Either .NET or JS would have been acceptable. I ended up answering my own question, because I found out that you can convert to IANA time zones in .NET 6. (I am actually quite surprised that I didn't stumble upon a JavaScript library that could do the conversion.)

Comment: You might take a look at my answer, you could use moment.js for javascript as a library

Comment: Moment.js does not solve this issue, @MrJami, because it uses IANA time zones, and what I have is a Windows time zone. (This is also the reason that I didn't accept your answer.)

Comment: Ah I see, I am sorry for that. I would take a look on it and let you know

Comment: I updated my answer and added a library to it :) there you go.

Comment: Oh - I hadn't noticed that. https://github.com/rubenillodo/windows-iana is pretty neat. Thanks for linking to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key was to understand that `"Romance Standard Time"` is a **Windows time zone ID**. Everyone else uses **IANA time zone IDs**. They have the region/city format, e.g. `"Europe/Copenhagen"`.

In .NET 6 it's possible to convert between the formats. Here's the code example from [Date, Time, and Time Zone Enhancements in .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#time-zone-conversion-apis).

```cs
// Conversion from Windows to IANA when a region is unknown.
string windowsTimeZoneId = "Eastern Standard Time";
if (!TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertWindowsIdToIanaId(
    windowsTimeZoneId, out string ianaTimeZoneId))
{
    throw new TimeZoneNotFoundException(
        $"No IANA time zone found for "{windowsTimeZoneId}".");
}
Console.WriteLine($"{windowsTimeZoneId} => {ianaTimeZoneId}");
// "Eastern Standard Time => America/New_York"
```

```cs
// Conversion from Windows to IANA when a region is known.
string windowsTimeZoneId = "Eastern Standard Time";
string region = "CA"; // Canada
if (!TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertWindowsIdToIanaId(
    windowsTimeZoneId, region, out string ianaTimeZoneId))
{
    throw new TimeZoneNotFoundException(
       $"No IANA time zone found for "{windowsTimeZoneId}" in "{region}".");
}
Console.WriteLine($"{windowsTimeZoneId} + {region} => {ianaTimeZoneId}");
// "Eastern Standard Time + CA => America/Toronto"
```

If you're on an earlier version of .NET you can use [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter). Here's a complete list of the time zones in case you need to build your own converter: [windowsZones.json](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr-json/blob/83f6144d8aa3d10e932c25924d4c903925b24257/cldr-json/cldr-core/supplemental/windowsZones.json).

This answer to this questions suggests using NodaTime, so that is probably also a possibility: [Convert Windows timezone to moment.js timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088984/convert-windows-timezone-to-moment-js-timezone)

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript**

If you want to do it with Javascript, there is multiple Libraries. I am most familiar with [moment.js](https://momentjs.com), however they are deprecated, which means you might want to use another library if you are working on a new project.

[List of suggested libraries by moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Anyways, if you wish to work with moment and convert to timezones, you could easily do that using [Moment-Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). [All supported timezones](https://gist.github.com/diogocapela/12c6617fc87607d11fd62d2a4f42b02a).

For example:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const timeZone = "Europe/Paris";

const ISOString = "2022-01-06T13:35:00Z"; //2022-01-06T13:35:00Z
const momentDefault = moment(ISOString).format(); //2022-01-06T14:35:00+01:00
const momentTz = moment.utc(ISOString).tz(timeZone).format(); //2022-01-06T14:35:00+01:00
```

As you see, moment gets the timezone by default and handels the ISOString as a UTC value, so it automatically converts the value to the timezone of the client user.

You still can specifically tell moment to handle the ISOString as a UTC ISOString and then convert it to a specific Timezone you defined. In that way the client's timezone will be ignored.

**EDIT:**
Now I realized that the questioner wants to convert the timezone from Windows to Iana before converting it in Javascript, because most libraries including Moment.js don't support windows timezone ids.

I found a nice library [here](https://github.com/rubenillodo/windows-iana).

And here is an example how to convert the timezone first and then use moment.js.

```
import { findIana } from 'windows-iana';
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

const result = findIana('Romance Standard Time');
console.log(result); // ['Europe/Paris', 'Europe/Brussels', 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'Europe/Madrid', 'Africa/Ceuta']
const timeZone = result[0]; //doesn't really matter which one to take, if you are just converting the times.

const ISOString = "2022-01-06T13:35:00Z"; //2022-01-06T13:35:00Z
const momentDefault = moment(ISOString).format(); //2022-01-06T14:35:00+01:00
const momentTz = moment.utc(ISOString).tz(timeZone).format(); //2022-01-06T14:35:00+01:00
```

**.NET C#**

To convert a time to a specific timezone in C#, you dont need any extra packages, you can simply do that as following:

```
var isoString = "2022-01-06T13:35:00Z";
var utcDate= DateTime.Parse(isoString);
var timeZone = "Romance Standard Time";
var date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcDate, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone)); //01/06/2022 14:35:00
```

Here you can find list of [all supported timezoneIds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7908482/14259165)