# How to get current time by passing timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript

is it possible to get the current time by providing timezone in javascript?
Here I have-
timezone - `America/Detroit`

```
var d = new Date();
```

is it possible to get current time by providing America/Detroit ?

Comment: I presume you're asking because you are not in that timezone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+time+from+timezone+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70608037/how-can-use-romance-standard-time-to-set-the-time-zone/70608565#70608565) is an example how to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207655/get-time-of-specific-timezone

Answer (score 0):

```
let date = new Date;
```

let strTime = date.toLocaleString("en-US", {
timeZone: 'America/Detroit'
});
console.log(timeZone, strTime);